# SFTP authentication failing

Tags: ssh, samba, fedora, sftp

I am trying to setup sftp access for our customers to download or upload files.  While trying to setup the directory permissions and user access I keep getting errors as such.

```
server1 sshd[21760]: Accepted password for user01 from 192.168.1.118 port 51026 ssh2
server1 sshd[21760]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user user01 by (uid=0)
server1 sshd[21775]: fatal: bad ownership or modes for chroot directory "/home/user01"
server1 sshd[21760]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user user01
```

I have the following setup in the sshd_config file:

```
Match Group sftp_users
ChrootDirectory %h
ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

Folder/file permissions show as this:

```
drwxr-xr-x 4 user01 sftp_users 4096 Mar 28 09:26 /home/user01
```

I have a mounted drive as such:

```
//windowserver/ftproot/customers/user01 on /home/user01 type cifs (rw)
```

What I am failing to understand/determine is if the user "user01" has read/write access to it's own home directory on the local machine, but when using ssh/sftp the error of "bad ownership/modes" is returned.  Is it because the session for user01 is opened by uid=0?  In this case the uid for user01 is 502, while the uid for root is 0.

If additional information is needed from what I have given here, please let me know and I'll post that info.

Comment: I forgot to include that if I comment out the ChrootDirectory parameter in sshd_config file that user01 is then able to connect via sftp but has full access to the server file structure (not at all ideal).  That's why I'm using Chroot Directory to limit access to just the user's home directory.

Comment: Have you seen this post? https://askubuntu.com/questions/134425/how-can-i-chroot-sftp-only-ssh-users-into-their-homes

Comment: Thank you for this post, this (as well as another answer) helped me complete the configuration to meet the read/write access our customers will need.

Comment: Hi Andrew, please consider removing your question or write an answer with your findings. This will help improve the quality of the content on ServerFault!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the help/suggestion of others, I learned that if you add a subfolder to the user's home directory and setting that subfolder to be chown'd by the user that it all works as expected.  To summarize:

```
/home/user01 should be chown'd by root.
/home/user01/shared should be chown'd by user01
```

Then when user01 logs in they only see the folder named shared but they cannot navigate to the parent folders above shared. And since the user01 login has ownership user01 can read & write files from/to that directory.

Answer (score 0):

Chroot directory should be the parent of the target so in this case /home

```
ChrootDirectory /home
```